# jquery-ajax DELETE request throws 403 access denied error

Tags: php, jquery, rest, http-status-code-403

The following function is called when a user clicks on a button.

```
function clearTable() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'cleartable.php',
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {}
    });
}
```

This works the way I want it to when tested on my localhost server, i.e. `clearTable()` invokes `cleartable.php`, which in turn does`TRUNCATE TABLE tablename`.

However, when I run it on my remote server, Chrome's javascript console I prints the error message:

> DELETE URL_TO_MY_REMOTE_SERVER/cleartable.php 403 (Access Denied)
>   jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5

A workaround is to change `type` to `POST` or `GET` and then it will successfull call the php. However, I want to know what is causing the DELETE request to fail. It's working for my localhost, so why is it not working on my remote server then? Also, based on REST, it makes more sense for request type to be DELETE, since I am deleting something on the server, right?

Comment: I would guess that it violates the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript), when you send it to the remote server.

Comment: Check the server configuration. For example apache `mod_security` module may filter some types of requests.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - my answer is based upon my experience with Apache, though it may be relevant for other server software.

I was running into this same problem with a client's site, and it appeared that the relevant VirtualDirectory entry in their httpd.conf file was denying DELETE requests, hence the 403 Forbidden error.

I am still waiting for their reply to see if allowing DELETE requests resolved this error, but thought I'd post my findings here in the hope that it may explain what you were seeing.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. Is there any way to fix this problem, given I have full access to the server?

Comment: If you have full access, and haven't yet checked your .conf file, I'd suggest that first, to make sure the VirtualDirectory entry for the site allows DELETE requests. Keep in mind, you'll need to restart Apache after making a change like this.

Comment: I tried a lot of solutions suggested for allowing DELETE requests but none worked for me. I'm using laravelphp5 which uses symphony components and was able to use POST and specify the API method in request body. Reference - http://laravel.io/forum/02-20-2014-sending-a-delete-request-via-ajax. This is how I solved my problem. I know it's a server config and couldn't fix it. Addl info: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with LAMP stack on AWS EC2.